# setting an uitableview cell a tag and retriving it

Tags: iphone

i have tried to set up a uitableview cell to be given a tag however i am not sure how to get the cell to become tagged on user input (uibutton) and then the code required to retrieve the multiple items or single item tagged.

Comment: Um. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: adding a tag to a uitableview cell and depending on user input tagging that cell for retrieval in another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without understanding exactly what you plan to do, `indexPath` points to the selected cell.

If you try to keep object references you could move all information you need to an instance variable type `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.